# Share Text on Facebook from iphone app with URL Schemes

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, url, url-scheme

As I can compatir text in facebook by URL Schemes earlier in iOS 6 could do it with the following line:

```
fb://publish/profile/#me?text=someText
```

But in iOS 7 and with the new version of the Facebook app this action does absolutely nothing.

Comment: Why not use the build iOS social sharing, [Activity View Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/ContentViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW121)

Comment: I think is a good solution but not working in iphone 4 in iOS7.

Comment: The solution should work from iOS 6 and up. If it is not working on you device it might be because your are not logged into facebook in the settings.